# Sorting column and filtering for top results, grouping by multiindex level 0 (Series / DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group out the top results for each element in the index at level 0. For example with this dataframe / series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

index = list(zip(['A']*5 + ['B']*5, list(range(10))))
df = pd.Series(np.random.random((10)),
               index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index, names=['i0', 'i1']),
               name='val')

pd.DataFrame(df)
```

[image]

I would like to keep `A` and `B` grouped and return the top 3 `val`'s (descending) from each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).head(3))

i0  i1
A   1     0.720324
    0     0.417022
    3     0.302333
B   9     0.538817
    8     0.396767
    7     0.345561
```

Answer (score 4):

Another similar option here:

```
(df.sort_values('val', ascending=False).groupby(level=0).head(3)
   .sort_index(level = 0, sort_remaining=False, kind="mergesort"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to waste time sorting, use `nlargest`

```
df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(3)

i0  i1
A   1     0.720324
    0     0.417022
    3     0.302333
B   9     0.538817
    8     0.396767
    7     0.345561
Name: val, dtype: float64
```